# Direct SQL Query vs. EXEC

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a query which is being executed via LINQ to SQL. The query looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT DISTINCT [t2].[ID],...
FROM 
    Table1 AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS [t1] ON [t0].[Table1ID] = [t1].[Table1ID]
    INNER JOIN Table3 AS [t2] ON [t2].[Table2ID] = [t0].[Table2ID]
WHERE 
    ([t2].[Visible] = @p0) 
    AND ([t1].[AncestorID] IN (@p1,...,@p277))',N'@p0 int,...,@p277 int',@p0=1,...@p277=2875
```

As you can see it is basically an in-clause query with 277 parameters. Using exec and passing the parameters as above, the query takes **20 seconds**.

If I pull the query out of the exec call and run it "normally" it takes less **than one second**. Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @p0 int;
...
DECLARE @p277 int;

SET @p0=1;
...
SET @p277=287;

SELECT DISTINCT [t2].[ID],...
    FROM 
        Table1 AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS [t1] ON [t0].[Table1ID] = [t1].[Table1ID]
        INNER JOIN Table3 AS [t2] ON [t2].[Table2ID] = [t0].[Table2ID]
    WHERE 
        ([t2].[Visible] = @p0) 
        AND ([t1].[AncestorID] IN (@p1,...,@p277))
```

The third test, when I wrap the second query inside an exec, it **works instantly** still. So the problem seems to be with passing the parameters along in the exec call.

Comment: I'm guessing the (implied) question is, "How do I make this run faster?"

Comment: How does this relate to LINQ?

Comment: The first query is what LINQ-to-SQL produces. And the question is "why are these queries, which are the same at the core, running at different speeds."

Comment: @Josh M. - Did you try running it twice in a row through `sp_executesql`?  you could be seeing the effects of caching, and the first run did all the work pulling the data pages and creating the exec plan.

Comment: Yes I've ran it numerous times...19-20 seconds every time.

Comment: @Josh - Have you checked the execution plan?

Comment: Yes, and as expected, they are different. But I don't think they SHOULD be different...

Answer (score 1):

> So the problem seems to be with
>   passing the parameters along in the
>   exec call.

I think that you for some reason have different execution plans.

Here is an article by Erland Sommarskog that could be helpful for you to figure out what is going on.

[Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue likely has to do with "Parameter Sniffing" and the article linked by @Mikael talks about that. Unfortunately, this is one of the main down-sides to using an ORM as you lose the ability to tweak the SQL for performance.

Here are some things to try:

1. Run DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and run
   the query from the app again to see
   if that has any difference. Running
   it multiple times will not get a new
   execution plan because it is already
   cached from the first run.
2. Be sure to rebuild the indexes on the
   Tables to make sure that the
   statistics are up to date (a
   rebuild, not defrag should
   automatically update the stats)
3. If need be, you can always convert this
   operation to a Stored Procedure and call
   that from LINQ-to-SQL. You just might then
   have to pass in the list of values as a comma-
   separated list or XML. If you are on SQL Server
   2008 (or newer) the best solution would be to
   construct a DataTable on the app side and pass
   that into the Proc as a Table-Valued Parameter
   and use that in an INNER JOIN instead of an IN list.

Also, your second and third tests are basically the same as Ad Hoc queries have their plans cached with a key based on the EXACT text of the query, including spaces, etc. So wrapping it in an EXEC really shouldn't change how the optimizer sees it.